# Remove a Job release in Talend Open Studio

Tags: version-control, versioning, talend, data-integration

I'm using Talend Open Studio for Data Integration and I created a new release of an initial Job (release 0.1 at creation time) which is now release 0.2

I want to come back to my first release as the working copy and suppress the 0.2 one.

Is this possible in the "open" (ie free) version of Talend Studio ?
How can I do ?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Go to Window-->show view-->general-->Navigator-->Project Name folder-->process
- Delete the three files: "jobName_0.2.item", "jobName_0.2.properties" and "jobName_0.2.screenshot"
- Restart the Studio.